# How to determine type of an expression inside string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rest

I have one rest call that gives me information from query parameters and I need to determine whether they are a string or an int, array, boolean.

For example, if I have:

**/.../something?id=1**

I'll receive '1', but I know that's an **integer**.

Furthermore, I have:

**/.../something?id=[1,2,3]**

I'll receive '[1,2,3]' but I know it's an **array**. Finally, if I have:

**/.../something?id=string**

I'll receive 'string' and I should use it as a regular **string**.

Is regex the only way of doing that check for each type?

Comment: can you share your attempt up to the point where you have fetched that value after `?id=`?

Comment: You can apply`JSON.parse`, then `parseInt/parseFloat` and if both fail it must be a regular string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse` with a catch block.

```js
var options = ['12', '[1,2,3]', 'string', 'false', '{"x" : 2}', '/hey/', /hey/];

var parsed = options.map(x => {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(x)
    } catch(e) {
        return x;
    }

});

var types = parsed.map(x => /\[object (.*)\]$/.exec(Object.prototype.toString.call(x))[1])

console.log(types);
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, I'll try that soon and let you know if it works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a `value`

```
var value = "1"; //or whatever value after `id=`
```

you can apply this logic

```
var type = "";
var isNum = ( s ) => !isNaN(s);
var isObject = ( s ) => {
   try { s = JSON.parse(s); return Array.isArray(s) ? "array" : "object" } catch( e ){ return false }
};
```

Now use them as

```
type = isNum( value ) ? "number" : ( isObject( s ) || "string" );
```

**Note**

- If `value` is a function definition, it will still return a `string`

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use trial-and-error methodologies:

1. If you have the value starting from `[` and ending with `]`, you probably can assume that its an array. Use `JSON.parse` to be sure.
2. If first case doesn't match, use `/^\d+$/` to test the string against integer values. Use `parseInt()` to be sure.
3. Lastly, if above both test cases fail, you can be sure that its a string, because strings can hold almost all type of values.

Comment: So it's basically a regex test, then? I was wondering if Javascript didn't have any libraries on helping me so. But I think maybe it's the case I create a helper with the most used types and check each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Savio,

One way you can handle it is to fetch the value and use switch/case statement with 'typeof' to see what they are.

[Typeof explanation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```
// Numbers

typeof 37 === 'number';
typeof 3.14 === 'number';

// Strings
typeof 'bla' === 'string';

// Booleans
typeof true === 'boolean';

// use Array.isArray or Object.prototype.toString.call
// to differentiate regular objects from arrays
typeof [1, 2, 4] === 'object';
```

Comment: This doesn't work because in all cases typeof will return string, appreciate the effort though :)

Comment: even after using json.parse, it still shows as string?